# Execute Class Method from system.schedule method

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written an scheduler class inside which I have methods too,
so that I can schedule the same class at different schedule time and the methods works based on current time,
MY CODE

```
global class testclass Implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
        {
            String t= String.valueOf(System.now());
            integer t1 = integer.valueOf(t.substring(11,13));
            if(t1<13)
            {
                morningfn();
            }
            else 
            {
                eveningfn();    
            }
        }
   morningfn()
   {
   //CODE
   }
   eveningfn()
   {
   //CODE
   }
 }
```

I have Scheduled the small class twice a day i.e.morning 8 and evening 5 
so it will class the function based on the current time and this is working fine.
but while writing test class

```
@isTest
public class testclasstest {
@isTest Static void test1(){
testclass  tc = new testclass ();
String sch = '0 30 10 * * ?';
System.schedule('morning', sch, tc);
System.schedule('evening', sch, tc);
    }

}
```

When I execute this test it ll be always 53% based on what time executing either before 13 i.e.1PM (Morning function) or after 13 (evening function).

I can achieve 100% if i remove if-then or make 2 different class or scheduler class but i want to achieve everything in single class.

is there any way I can call function name in system.schedule method????
or any other solution Plz Help.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please try this. The solution is to override the t variable from test class

    Main class
    //global variable 
    public Integer timeFromTest;
    public Boolean flag = false;

    String t= String.valueOf(System.now());
    integer t1 = integer.valueOf(t.substring(11,13));
    if(flag) {
        t = timefromTest ;
    }


test class:
//1st time
scheduleClass.flag = true;
Scheduleclass.timefromtest = 14;
//2nd time
Scheduleclass.timefromtest = 10;
```

Comment: Thank you @Shravan, this is quite easy but I got the following error                              **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Test.isRunningTest()**           
 not only this whenever I use TEST like test.starttest or test.stoptest I get this error can u explain why??

Comment: Modified answer. 'Test' class scope is with in the test class(means it should be @isTest).

Comment: Thanks @Shravan You saved me lot of time its working, and I had some dummy class with name 'test' so it was throwing error I deleted that class now test.isRunningtest() is working.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the "@testVisible" attribute to your private methods, so you can call them directly from the unit tests, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm